# Tile only one window in Windows10

Tags: windows-10, aero-snap, tiles

Okay, whenever I want to tile a window on the right I hit <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>, and I tile my window.  And I'm fine with that, that's what I want.   However Windows always wants me to tile another window on the left, and minimizes the rest of the windows that are open for me to choose one.

I'd like help to disable this second part of the process of tiling. That is, I'd like to tile my window and have it tiled and continue with my workflow.  Instead of always having to cancel the choosing of the second window to tile.

This is a minor issue that I can go around every time.  The reason I'm asking for help is that I do this so many times in the day, that it somehow became a little annoying.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open start menu and type *Snap*, then click *Snap Settings*. In the settings window just uncheck *"When I snap a window, show what I can snap next to it"*

[image: Snap settings]

Comment: Thanks!!  That was easier than it needed. Thanks